# calculate distance between two chains in PDB file

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have 300 pdb fies with 2 chains. I want to calculate the distance between the first atom of first chain to all atoms of second chain.Then,second atom of first chain to all  atoms of second chain.  This has to be repeated for 300 files. I need to print the atom pairs only if the distance is >= 5 and save the outputs to another folder with input file names. The formula for finding distance is sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2+(z1-z2)^2). $5 is the chain ID and $12 is the atom name. $7, $8, $9 are the x,y,z coordinates. Your valuable suggestions would be appreciated!!

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     -16.220  53.312  36.564  1.00 32.19           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1     -15.722  52.290  37.522  1.00 28.47           C
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1     -14.451  51.635  37.011  1.00 26.82           C 
ATOM   2542  CG  ASN B  17      -1.077   9.776  13.155  1.00 18.23           C  
ATOM   2543  OD1 ASN B  17      -0.563   9.098  12.250  1.00 18.58           O 
ATOM   2544  ND2 ASN B  17      -0.632   9.746  14.418  1.00 14.82           N
```

Desired output (distance values are incorrect)

```
N-C   8.90
N-O   10.3
N-N   7.62
C-C   12.45
C-O   9.0
C-N   9.89 
C-C   11.45
C-O   19.0
C-N   10.89
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating distances with awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685335/calculating-distances-with-awk)

Comment: wild  guess is you are changing the user and writing the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file{,}
```

Contents of `script.awk`

```
NR==1 {
    n = $5
}

FNR==NR && $5 != n {
    a[c++]=$0
}

FNR!=NR && $5 == n {
    for (i=0;i<=c-1;i++) {
        split (a[i],b)
        dist = sqrt (($7-b[7])^2 + ($8-b[8])^2 + ($9-b[9])^2)
        if (dist >= 5) {
            printf "%s-%s\t%.2f\n", $NF, b[NF], dist
        }
    }
}
```

Tab separated results:

```
N-C 51.70
N-O 52.83
N-N 51.30
C-C 51.14
C-O 52.29
C-N 50.71
C-C 50.00
C-O 51.14
C-N 49.56
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1 { n = $5 } FNR==NR && $5 != n { a[c++]=$0 } FNR!=NR && $5 == n { for (i=0;i<=c-1;i++) { split (a[i],b); dist = sqrt (($7-b[7])^2 + ($8-b[8])^2 + ($9-b[9])^2); if (dist >= 5) printf "%s-%s\t%.2f\n", $NF, b[NF], dist } }' file{,}
```

So to perform this on multiple files in the present working directory, and assuming there's nothing but files of interest in this directory, you can wrap a `for` loop around the `awk` statement. Obviously, you'll need to change `/path/to/folder/` to your path of choice for it to work correctly:

```
for i in *; do awk 'NR==1 { n = $5 } FNR==NR && $5 != n { a[c++]=$0 } FNR!=NR && $5 == n { for (i=0;i<=c-1;i++) { split (a[i],b); dist = sqrt (($7-b[7])^2 + ($8-b[8])^2 + ($9-b[9])^2); if (dist >= 5) printf "%s-%s\t%.2f\n", $NF, b[NF], dist > "/path/to/folder/" FILENAME } }' "$i"{,}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MDAnalysis module for Python -- http://code.google.com/p/mdanalysis/

http://code.google.com/p/mdanalysis/wiki/Examples#Extracting_a_chain_from_a_PDB

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with your sample data saved as "test":

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import re

class Atom:
    def __init__ (self, line):
        tokens = re.split (' +', line)
        self.chain = tokens [4]
        self.x = float (tokens [6] )
        self.y = float (tokens [7] )
        self.z = float (tokens [8] )
        self.name = tokens [11]

    def __repr__ (self):
        return self.name

    def distance (self, other):
        return ( (self.x - other.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other.y) ** 2 + (self.z - other.z) ** 2) ** .5

chains = [ [], [] ]

with open ('test', 'r') as pdb:
    for line in pdb.readlines ():
        atom = Atom (line.strip () )
        chains [0 if atom.chain == 'A' else 1].append (atom)

print ('\n'.join ( ['{} - {}\t{}'.format (a, b, a.distance (b) ) for a in chains [0] for b in chains [1] ] ) )
```

produces something like that:

```
N - C   51.697920905970676
N - O   52.8317143484858
N - N   51.29744063791097
C - C   51.14359109409506
C - O   52.28783920760161
C - N   50.709908814747436
C - C   50.001484907950484
C - O   51.140786403808846
C - N   49.559022700210704
```

.

**EDIT:**

I forgot about your >= 5.0 condition: just replace the last line with:

```
print ('\n'.join ( ['{} - {}\t{}'.format (a, b, a.distance (b) ) for a in chains [0] for b in chains [1] if a.distance (b) >= 5.0] ) )
```